# What's the difference between the JUnit and the TestNG

Tags: junit, testng

Both Testng and Junit are Testing framework used for Unit Testing. So what are the diffrences and advantages of JUnit and the TestNG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Unit Testing Frameworks**

Both JUnit and TestNG are Testing framework used for Unit Testing. TestNG is similar to JUnit. Few more functionalities are added to it that makes TestNG more powerful than JUnit. TestNG is a testing framework inspired by JUnit and NUnit.

**Differences**

[image: Featyre Comparison]

**Advantages of TestNG**

1. TestNG Annotations are easy to understand over JUnit.
2. No constraints like declaring @BeforeClass and @AfterClass in
   TestNG, which are present in JUnit.
3. As method name constraint is present in JUnit, such method name
   constraint is not present in TestNG and you can specify any test
   method names.
4. TestNG enables you to group test cases easily which is not possible
   in JUnit. TestNG supports following three 3 additional
   setUp/tearDown level: @Before/AfterSuite, @Before/AfterTest and
   @Before/AfterGroup.
5. TestNG do not require extend any class.
6. TestNG allows to execute test cases based on group which isn't
   possible in JUnit.
7. Parallel execution of Selenium test cases is possible in TestNG.

Comment: This seem to be based on old data. Most of these differences seem to no longer apply.